# Vs Code : Error: could not open `C:\Users\folder-name'

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I was trying to implement a Spring boot application on vs code and came up with this error when I tried to run the code (Screenshot below). I am not clear what this error indicates and did not know what exactly to look for on the internet. could anyone tell me how I can resolve this error?

edit:
as I was told to copy-paste the error message as text, here it is.

```
PS D:\study material\java code\springbootdemo>  cd 'd:\study material\java code\springbootdemo'; & 'c:\Users\manjeet arneja\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.27.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.6.10-hotspot\bin\java.exe' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '@C:\Users\manjeet' 'arneja\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_9w87n9v9bnokxm9i3k10qtvnm.argfile' 'com.explore.springbootdemo.DemoApplication'
Error: could not open `C:\Users\manjeet'
```

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: You have a stray quote at one point in your string. If you copy-paste the error message as text in the question I can point it out. In general *always* post text as text, never as a picture.

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with neither of the tags you used. It's a problem with PS

Comment: don't use an image of an error message, copy/paste the text in the question, it is very hard to search for error-text in image

Comment: don't use spaces in **ANY** file name or directory name or user name

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, my bad. is it possible for you to tell what PS is or maybe lead me to something I can refer to?

Comment: @rioV8, will keep in mind next time!

Comment: @manjeetsingh10 PS is PowerShell, basically Windows' latest command line shell.

Comment: Gotcha!. Thanks for the quick response @FedericoklezCulloca.

Comment: Hey @FedericoklezCulloca, could you point out the mistake you were talking about in the previous comment?, as I have edited the question and posted the error as text.

Comment: What can't be opened? And what should it be? and then look at the command where this text is visible.

Comment: umm, I could not understand what you meant by "and then look at the command where this text is visible." @rioV8.

Comment: Read the error message.

Comment: @manjeetsingh10 here `'@C:\Users\manjeet' 'arneja\AppData\Local` remove those quotation marks between `manjeet` and `arneja`

Comment: Also, Thank you @rioV8 for your time. :')